# Splunk Alert - exclude IP address from time range only

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to to build a Splunk Alert whose aim is to detect if a user account has been used. In this alert, I want to exclude a time range (between 5 to 6 a.m.) every Tuesday and Thursday. During this time, the account is supposed to be used legitimately. During this time frame I also want to exclude the IP address of the server that is using it.

To clarify, let's say that we have a server with the IP `10.10.10.5/32`. This server uses the account `useraccount` each Tuesday and Thursday between 05:00 and 06:00. I need the Splunk Alert to search for any usage of the account, even on `10.10.10.5`, but for the time period above, exclude `10.10.10.5` from the alert search, if that makes sense.

This is what I have so far, and I haven't been able to figure out a way to also exclude the server's IP address during this time frame.

```
index=firewall  [search sourcetype="pan_panorama" AND "useraccount"]
| where NOT ( (date_wday=="tuesday" OR date_wday=="thursday")  AND NOT (date_hour >= 5 AND date_hour < 6) )
```

If I try with this:

```
index=firewall  [search sourcetype="pan_panorama" AND "useraccount"]
| where NOT ( (date_wday=="tuesday" OR date_wday=="thursday")  AND NOT (date_hour >= 5 AND date_hour < 6) AND NOT ("From: 10.10.10.5") )
```

I receive `Error in 'where' command: Typechecking failed. 'XOR' only takes boolean arguments.`

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. How can I build a Splunk Alert search that excludes a time period and an IP address only during that time period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splunk is choking on the `AND NOT "string"` part of the `where` command.  It doesn't make sense.  Compare the string to a field value and should work.

```
index=firewall sourcetype="pan_panorama" AND "useraccount"
| where NOT ( (date_wday=="tuesday" OR date_wday=="thursday")  
  AND date_hour = 5 AND cidrmatch(From, "10.10.10.5/32") )
```

Also, I think the double-negative logic doesn't produce the right results.  This query accepts all events except those on Tuesday or Thursday from 0500-0559 by IP address 10.10.10.5.
Furthermore, there's no need for a subsearch.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, the `From:` is a sting field in the log it seems. Do I need to extract it as a new field for the `cidrmatch` to work?

Comment: I came up with this: 


`index=firewall sourcetype="pan_panorama" AND "useraccount"
| where NOT ( (date_wday=="tuesday" OR date_wday=="thursday")  
  AND date_hour = 5 ) | search NOT ("From: 10.10.10.5" OR "From: 10.10.10.6")`


But it doesn't seem to work properly. If I change the dates to Sunday and Monday, for instance, it still hides any log in from the IP addresses despite the day or time selected. Any tips?

Comment: That query still tries to do boolean logic with strings.  "From: 10.10.10.5" would always be true if Splunk supported it, but it doesn't.  If it's not a field then make it one.
`index=firewall sourcetype="pan_panorama" AND "useraccount"
| rex "From:\s(?<From>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"
| where NOT ( (date_wday=="tuesday" OR date_wday=="thursday")  
  AND date_hour = 5 AND cidrmatch(From, "10.10.10.5/32") )`

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get `cidrmatch` to work, so what ended up working for me was:


`index=firewall sourcetype="pan_panorama" AND "useraccount" | rex "From:\s(?<From>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" | where NOT ( (date_wday=="tuesday" OR date_wday=="thursday")  AND date_hour = 5 AND (From="10.10.10.5" OR From="10.10.10.6"))`